# Is it possible to create python modules from Haxe code?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, haxe, sublime-text-plugin

I currently playing around with Haxe and Sublime to create a custom plugin. For certain purposes I need to import the sublime module in an own python module, but I didn't found a way to generate it from haxe.
To make it clear, not the import of other modules is the problem, which is easy to do with externs and the pythonImport flag, its more the structure of a python module which looks like:

```
import ...
import ...

def my_function1():
    'Doing awesome stuff'

def my_function2():
    'Doing much more awesome stuff'

...
```

Does anyone have an idea how to create those files from haxe? Or if it's even possible / I have to write these files in Python directly?

Thanks guys!

Comment: I don't have any knowledge of haxe, but [the manual](http://haxe.org/manual/compiler-usage.html) has a page on compiling to python. Looks like you simply call it with the flags `-cp inputclasspath -main inputmainmodule -python outputfilename.py`